# why do i get unhandled promise error when i make get request

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I am working on web scraping app.
I am trying to make get request to  get route in *NodeJS* I wrote some asynchronous code in the app.get Route but I get `unhandledPromiseRejection error`.
I declared the callback function in *app.get* so that I can make asynchronous to get response.

I used async await syntax as follow, what possibly is wrong here. Any help appreciated!

```
app.get('/', async (req,res) => {
  let USERNAME = req.query.search_name;

  const BASE_URL = `https://instagram.com/${USERNAME}`;

  let response = await request(BASE_URL);

});
```

the request doesn't succeed showing the `unhandledPromiseRejection` error

Comment: When asking for help, please take the time to punctuate and capitalize correctly, as it makes it much easier to read your question.

Comment: *"...showing the error unhandledPromiseRejection..."* That isn't the error it shows. That's the *beginning* of the error it shows. To help you with the underlying problem, we need to know what the actual error is.

Comment: ..i tried putting it is try catch block...it says StatusCodeError with StatusCode 404... i am trying to make get request from postman app with params.....the code was working fine as expected until i put it in app.get Route

Comment: So the question isn't "Why do [you] have an unhandled rejection," the question is "Why do [you] have a 404 error." We can't help you with that other than the obvious: The server  you're requesting the resource from is saying it can't find anything for that URL.

Comment: I am just starting out in this field. I am sorry for the inconvenience that i was unable to put my question properly. I solved the problem . I was making request in a wrong way. i used " " to define value for the key when passing params to the url, which i later found is not required...and thanks for the help!!!

Comment: Glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `async/await` you use the `try/catch` like this:

In general error handling with `async/await` is done with `try/catch` like:

```
async function someFunc() {
  try {
    // get resolved value
    const result = await getSomethingFromPromise();
  } catch (e) {
    // handle error rejected from a promise
    console.error(e)
  }
}
```

As **T.J Crowder** have mentioned (and *emphasized* (: ), it's better to wrap try catch around whole body. Also you can use multiple await within the same block.

```
app.get('/', async (req,res) => {
  try {
    let USERNAME = req.query.search_name;
    // multiple await
    // const result = await someOtherPromise();
    const BASE_URL = `https://instagram.com/${USERNAME}`;
    let response = await request(BASE_URL);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
});
```

Comment: @T.J Crowder yes, right. Just did it around where await was used to make the syntax clear, so someone new could clearly get how it *can* be used. (:

Comment: This will help the OP with the "unhandled rejection" part, but not the primary issue. Sadly, we *can't* help them with the primary issue, since they haven't told us what the error is.

Answer (score -1):

Because you have not catch error.

```
app.get('/', async (req,res) => {
  let USERNAME = req.query.search_name;

  const BASE_URL = `https://instagram.com/${USERNAME}`;
  try {
    let response = await request(BASE_URL);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
});
```

Make sure you get the async/await in a try catch block.

Read more : 
https://alligator.io/js/async-functions/

https://hackernoon.com/understanding-async-await-in-javascript-1d81bb079b2c